# Losing quality of image while changing from pdf to image using PythonMagick

Tags: python, image, pdf, imagemagick, pythonmagick

I am working on changing pdfs to images using PythonMagick.
I am successfully changing the formats, but the quality of the image is diminished during this process.

This is the code that i am using.

```
sample_pdf="test_pdf"
sample_image="test_image"

pdf='/home/path/'+sample_pdf+''
image='/home/path/images/'+sample_image+''

im = PythonMagick.Image(pdf)
im.write(image)
```

I am losing the quality of image by this process.

While researching i found that the below code helps in retaining the quality of the image by using ImageMagick

```
convert -density 300 source.pdf -quality 80 target.jpg
```

is there something similar in PythonMagick? I cant seem to find any, online.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the `density` and `quality` methods of your instance?

```py
sample_pdf="test_pdf"
sample_image="test_image"

pdf='/home/path/{}'.format(sample_pdf)
image='/home/path/images/{}'.format(sample_image)

im = PythonMagick.Image(pdf)
im.density("300")
im.quality(80)
im.write(image)
```

You should have look at the [API documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/Image.html).

Comment: worked for me .. thanks payet. A small doubt though, couldnt find the difference with density of 1000 or 100 value, can you tell me what exactly density does?

Answer (score 2):

```
import PythonMagick

sample_pdf="test_pdf"
sample_image="test_image"

pdf='/home/path/'+sample_pdf+''
image='/home/path/images/'+sample_image+''

im = PythonMagick.Image()
im.density("300")
im.read(pdf)
im.quality(100)
im.write(image)
```

This worked like a charm for me.
Thanks once again Payet.